# Magento not sending email

Tags: php, xml, email, magento

We are using Apptha Airhotels module with Magento. This seems to be the easiest way to send email we've found thus far but we just can't seem to get this to work.

We are already receiving emails such as registration confirmation so mail server is functioning correctly.

We are also using cpanel to track if the email is being sent.

```
$emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                    ->loadDefault('airhotels_email_contact_me');

$emailTemplateVariables = array();
$emailTemplateVariables['myvar1'] = 'My Variable1';
$emailTemplateVariables['myvar2'] = 'My Variable2';
$emailTemplateVariables['myvar3'] = 'My Variable3';

// For testing purposes only
$processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
echo $processedTemplate;
// Echoing prints properly the processed email so the template is working correctly

$emailTemplate->send('mailrecipient@domain.com','John Doe', $emailTemplateVariables);
```

contactmeform.html:

```
<body> 
<div>
<h1>Test</h1>
<p>{{var myvar1}}<br/>{{var myvar2}}<br/>{{var myvar3}}.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

config.xml:

```
 <airhotels_email_contact_me module="airhotels">
 <label>Contact me</label>
 <file>airhotels/contactmeform.html</file>
 <type>html</type>
 </airhotels_email_contact_me>
```

Comment: are you testing this code on your localhost ?

Comment: You need to install a Mail Server.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy Nope. We are using Arvixe's servers.

Comment: Can you show us the code of your email template html file? (airhotels_email_contact_me)

Comment: @AliGajani Other emails such as registration confirmation are working  correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a sender and subject, which is required.
Because now `isValidForSend()` that is called before sending email will return false.

Try to add:

```
$emailTemplate->setSenderName(‘name sender’);
$emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(‘test@email.com’);
$emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject(‘Email Subject’);
```

Comment: Adding the $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject(‘Email Subject’); fixed our problems! Thank you.